# in Objective-c, if structure is not initialized, what value does its member return?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to know height of a view.

```
NSInteger height = view.frame.size.height;
```

In above code, `frame` and `size` are structure and `view` is object.
If `view` is nil in the above code, what value does `height` return?

I know that I get nil if I send message to nil object.
But `size` is not object.

When I ran the above code, I get 0 if `view` is nil.
Does it always return 0, or returning 0 isn't guaranteed?

Also in the following code, height returns zero.

```
CGSize size;
NSInteger height = size.height;
```

In Objective-C, structures which are not initialized always returns zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example (`view.frame.size.height`), you are guaranteed to get 0 if `view` is nil.  This became true in Xcode 4.2 (using clang); for older compiler versions (and gcc I believe) the result is undefined.  Source: [Greg Parker's blog](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2012/2/29/objc_explain_return_value_of_message_to_nil.html).

For your second example, it depends on where `CGSize size;` is declared.  If it's a local variable like this:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    CGSize size;
    NSInteger height = size.height;
    ...
}
```

then `height` is undefined.  It might be zero, or it might be any other number.

If it's an instance variable like this:

```
@implementation MyObject {
    CGSize size;
}
```

then it is guaranteed to be initialized to zero by `+[MyObject alloc]`.

If it's a global variable like this:

```
// outside of any method, function, or class variable section
CGSize size;
```

(or a static variable) then it's guaranteed to be initialized to zero when your app launches.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer! Is it `permanently` guaranteed that view(nil).frame.size.height returns 0? Is it possible that this behavior will be changed by upgrades or changes of Xcode or compiler in the future?

Comment: thanks! But could you tell me why it's guaranteed, if possible?

Comment: Because if apple changed it, lots of existing code would break.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a structure that is not initialized. In fact, it's initialized to all zeroes by `objc_msgSend_stret()` exactly for this reason: structure returning messages sent to `nil` return 0 for all members.